# Read SD card files from an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read SD card contents through iPad Camera Connection Kit in iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488233/how-to-read-sd-card-contents-through-ipad-camera-connection-kit-in-ios-sdk)

I want to write an iOS app to access the data in a SD card via Apple's SD card reader. I am wondering what Framework in Xcode I need to import or I am allowed to develop this kind of app related to file access from external storage.

Answer (score 4):

As of yet, developers do not have access to the SD reader attachment.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it in the future.

Comment: Something has changed. iOS 13 finally allows this.

Answer (score 0):

The drive should get mounted in `/var/mnt`. Check out the Cydia app called iFile.